# Install npm (Node.js Package Manager) on Windows (w/o using Node.js MSI)

Tags: node.js, installation, npm

The problem: while using `nvm` to install Node.js I was able to install the version of Node.js I need, but `nvm` does not install `npm` automatically. NPM's page provides no information about installing it. Being not much of a Windows user myself I am completely at a loss...

Every result in Google seems to use Node.js MSI installer to get that working - which is not an option in my case. So, how do I?

Comment: https://npmjs.org/install.sh

Comment: Very possible, I recall using it to install npm in cygwin years back.

Answer (score 33):

To install npm on windows just unzip the npm [archive](http://nodejs.org/dist/npm/) where node is. See the [docs](https://github.com/isaacs/npm#fancy-windows-install) for more detail.

npm is shipped with node, that is how you should install it. nvm is only for changing node versions and does not install npm. A cleaner way to use npm and nvm is to first install node as it is (with npm), then install the [nvm](https://npmjs.org/package/nvm) package by `npm install nvm`

Comment: Please note, the NVM module no longer supports windows

https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/284

Comment: This answer was helpful. though I was in a different place than the OP. I accidentally uninstalled npm (don't ask) and couldn't install anything (including npm), and the [solution for Linux/Unix OSes](http://codybonney.com/reinstalling-npm-from-source-using-git/) wasn't applicable to me on Windows.

Comment: @RobertDundon Have you take a loot at my answer ?

Comment: @user568109 , To install npm on windows just unzip the npm archive "where node is", you mean in "C:\Program Files\nodejs"

Answer (score 21):

https://nodejs.org/download/ . The page has Windows Installer (.msi) as well as other installers and binaries.Download and install for windows.

Node.js comes with NPM.

NPM is located in the directory where Node.js is installed.

Comment: You will need to convert the npm shell script to a batch script.

Comment: Link might help to get the file faster: https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest/

Answer (score 12):

I used quite @Eyuel method:

- Download the nodejs msi from https://nodejs.org/en/#download
- Download npm zip from github https://github.com/npm/npm
- Extract the msi (with 7 Zip) in a directory "node"
- Set the PATH environment variable to add the "node" directory
- Extract the zip file from npm in a different directory (not under node directory)
- CD to the npm directory and run the command `node cli.js install npm -gf`

Now you should have node + npm working, use theses commands to check: `node --version` and `npm --version`

**Update 27/07/2017** : I noticed that the latest version of node 8.2.1 with the latest version of npm are quite different from the one I was using at the time of this answer. The install with theses versions won't work. It is working with node 6.11.1 and npm 5.2.3.
Also if you are running with a proxy don't forget this to connect on internet :

- export http_proxy=http://proxy:8080
- export https_proxy=http://proxy:8080
- npm config set proxy http://proxy:8080

Comment: Worked great for me, too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I also needed to install npm in Windows and got it through the Chocolatey pacakage manager. For those who haven't heard about it, Chocolatey is a package manager for Windows, that gives you the convenience of an apt-get in Windows environments. To get it go to https://chocolatey.org/ where there's a PowerShell script to download it and install it. After that you can run:

```
chocolatey install npm
```

and you're good to go.

Note that the standalone npm is no longer being updated and the last version that is out there is known to have problems on Windows. Another option you can look at is extracting npm from the MSI using [LessMSI](https://chocolatey.org/packages/lessmsi).

Comment: Chocolatey is a great option. Just discovered it, thanks to you! However I ran into some trouble. If anyone else had some hick-ups with this method (which really works flawlessly once you actually figured out how to get it to run), have a look at my [detailed run-through](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41085789/2228771)

Answer (score 8):

First CD to where node(nodejs) is installed using windows CMD, then follow the steps below

```
C:...\node> git config --system http.sslcainfo /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
C:...\node> git clone --recursive git://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
C:...\node> cd node=modules\npm
C:...\node=modules\npm> node cli.js install npm -gf
```

Answer (score 8):

Just download "node.exe" from http://nodejs.org/dist/, select your favorite "node.js" version or take the [latest](http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/). You can also take 64-bits version from "x64" sub-directory.

Then, go to http://nodejs.org/dist/npm/ to retrieve Zip-archive of your favorite "npm" version (recommanded : `1.4.10`). Extract the archive along "node.exe".

Finally, it is recommanded to add "node.js" directory to the PATH for convenience.

EDIT: I recommande to update npm using `npm install npm -g` because versions provided by nodejs.org are very old.

If you want to keep original npm version, don't put npm alongside `"node.exe"`. Just create a directory and use the same command with "global" flag, then copy `.\node_modules\.bin\npm.cmd` to the new directory :

```
mkdir c:\app\npm\_latest
cd c:\app\npm\_latest
<NPM_ORIGINAL_PATH>\npm install npm
cp node_modules\.bin\npm.cmd npm.cmd
```

Finally change your PATH to use `c:\app\npm\_latest`

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a quick simple app recent that handle the management of various version of node and npm.  It allows you to choose different version of node and npm to download and select which version to use.  Check it out and see if it's something that's useful.

https://github.com/nhatkthanh/wnm

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR: Install Chocolatey, Node (and NPM)

### Install Chocolatey

NOTE: You might want to copy the exact command from [their install page](https://chocolatey.org/install) since it might change over time.

1. Open your standard Windows command line
2. `@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "(iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))) >$null 2>&1" && SET PATH="%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"`
3. Restart console
4. Done!

### Install Node (and NPM)

1. Because Chocolatey installs a directory different from the MSI installation, go to your system configuration and delete your previous `node` installation (if you have one)
2. Install Chocolatey as described above
3. `choco install nodejs`

   > NOTE I used `nodejs`. I am not even sure what `node` is, but having had my fair share of troubles with `node` already being taken by something else in other systems, I thought, `nodejs` would be the safer bet right away
4. Restart your console
5. Beware: `node -v` works!

   - And `npm -v` also works! Awesome.

After this, I was able to install `firebase-tools` without problems (which I was not able to do previously), so something must have gone terribly right! :)

## My rather complete story the first time around

> "Chocolatey installs in seconds"

If you don't care about sarcasm or lamenting engineers on a Sunday afternoon, skip ahead to the installation instructions in the **TL;DR** section below.

For everyone else: I want to amend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000173/install-npm-node-js-package-manager-on-windows-w-o-using-node-js-msi/25980740#25980740) which recommends using (what seems to be the hottest package management solution for Windows right now): [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)

It gets the job done nice and quick. However, when I gave it a first try, it took me a while to make sense of the install instructions which are kinda convoluted. The install instructions go a bit like this (complete with what went through my head while going through it):

- **NOTE:**
- **NOTE:**
- **NOTE:**

  > three big-ass NOTEs before even knowing the basics... this makes me anxious... how wrong could things go!?
- **Installing With Restricted TLS**

  > not even sure what `TLS` is... Oh it's a good friend of `SSL` - Shouldn't this just be the default and just work out of the box? My browser can do `HTTPS`, NO PROBLEM! (just kidding... I know that `SSL` and `TSL` frequently cause a lot of pain in environments that have high security needs)
- **Option 1**
- **Option 2**

  > eeh... great... Can't I just install?
- **Installing Behind a Proxy?**

  > Just... no...
- **Requirements**

  > uh boi...
- **Why does Chocolatey install where it does by default?**

  > Seriously!?!
- **Before You Install**

  > [image: sad]
  >   <sub>(source: [clipartbest.com](http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/jix/Ekx/jixEkxaGT.png))</sub>
- **Can I install with a proxy?**

  > again with the proxy...
- **Can I install a particular version of Chocolatey?**

  > just any version would be fine, thank you...
- **Can I use Windows built-in compression instead of downloading 7zip?**

  > 7zip?! Why do you even mention this?!
- **Non-Administrative Install**
- > Now that sounds great!

  - "**NOTE**: This option should be a last resort and is considered to be an advanced scenario."

    - > Sh$%!@T.
- **Alternative Installation Options**

  > *giddy*
- **Command Line**

  - "This really is the easiest method because it requires no configuration of PowerShell prior to executing it."

    > And there you go!

While I really appreciate the fact that pitfalls and their possible solutions are discussed so extensively, maybe re-organizing them as such, and putting the `Chocolatey installs in seconds` promise to work by putting the "easiest method" first would be just awesome!

Comment: The answer is opinionated and tries to disgrace Chocolatey for no obvious reasons. Each platform favors specific way to install software and makes non-standard ways harder(much-harder). On Windows .exe or .msi was the user friendly way to install stuff for ages. Package management installing via PowerShell is kind of not right for Windows. To be honest, I installed Chocolatey in under a minute including tip for "those behind proxy". Before complaining just compare those two: http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/ns-setup-win and http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/ns-setup-os-x

Comment: @zmechanic I don't think I am trying to "disgrace" Chocolatey. It's a great tool! But thanks for the feedback. I made it a bit clearer that I actually like Chocolatey and it does get the job done (despite my lamenting).

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Window -> Preferences -> Nodeclipse and unchecking the box that says "find node on PATH...". Then make sure the "Node.js path" below is set to the location of the node.exe file (for me it was C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe).

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest Node.js MSI (4.x or 5.x) installer and run the following via command line:

```
msiexec /a node-v4.4.3-x64.msi /qb TARGETDIR="C:\Node.js"
```

This will extract the binaries into `C:\Node.js\nodejs`.

Then you will want to add `C:\Node.js\nodejs` `PATH` environment variable.

To update NPM, do the following:

```
cd C:\Node.js\nodejs
npm install npm@latest
```

After that completes, you should be able to check the versions:

```
node --version
npm --version
```

Node should be 4.4.3+ (whichever you installed) and npm should be 3.8.7+.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Windows 10 Creators Update (1703) and are comfortable navigating around a Unix terminal, you could potentially achieve this using the native Feature **[Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl/about)** (aka *Bash/WSL*)

> This was originally introduced on the launch of Build 2016 but many additions and bug fixes were addressed at the Creators update but please be warned this is still in Beta.

To enable simply navigate to **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features\Turn Windows features on or off**

Then select the **Windows Subsystem for Linux (Beta)** as below
[Bash on Windows Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yovel.png)