# How do I open NPM? I downloaded Node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm going through this [WebRTC Codelab](https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab) and they said you need node.js and socket.io to continue the tutorial. I downloaded node.js and to download socket.io, it says "run the following command: npm install socket.io". I don't know where to run this command, I don't want to do something I might regret later. There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000173/install-npm-node-js-package-manager-on-windows-w-o-using-node-js-msi) but it's 2 years old, I can't find the zip file they're referring to.

Comment: I dont know whats going on man, I got this weird ouput. it says build error in there somewhere

Comment: Then you're doing it correctly, and the build is failing for some reason. Open an issue here: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues?q=build+error+is%3Aissue and make sure you provide all relevant information (including the npm install output)

Answer (score 0):

On windows type `ctrl + r` then `cmd` in the run box.

If you want to globally install the package to any node.js project not just to the current project folder use the global flag `-g` type `npm install socket.io -g` hit enter.

Otherwise:

Navigate to your project folder using the `cd dir` command. Or shift right click in the folder and say open cmd window here.

type `npm install socket.io` hit enter

Comment: what run box? I didn't get a run box after ctrl + r